# Completely reproduce minionpro package behaviour in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, minionpro

The `minionpro` (or is it `MinionPro`?) package provides several font-defining commands that allow the user to customise small caps, wider small caps (`\textsc`, `\textssc`), swash letters (`\textsw`), font-provided slanted fractions, tabular, lining, oldstyle figures, and so on.

That said, *installing* Minion Pro for (pdf)LaTeX is a big chore, and I am intending to move to XeTeX with `fontspec` and `unicode-math`, with my recent purchase of Minion Math.

How might I start out replicating *all* the commands provided to the typesetter by `minionpro`?

Comment: `MinionPro.sty` does custom kerning for slanted fractions: `\newcommand*\@slantfrac[2]{%
  {\Mn@extra@font\@@numerator@fig{#1}\kern-0.05em/\kern-0.06em\@@denominator@fig{#2}}}`. Is that what you want to replicate? It also does `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\r}{OT1}{A}
     {\leavevmode\setbox\z@\hbox{!}\dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@-1ex%
     \ooalign{\hss\raise.67\dimen@\hbox{\char23}\hss\crcr A}}` which would be its own glyph in unicode (Å) and so wouldn't need replicating, if I understand the question correctly. Perhaps the question is simpler than it sounds.

Comment: That is likely true, but it might be a one-time effort rather than every user of Minion Pro going through the tedium of generating Type 1 glyphs from the OpenType, preparing a texmf tree and copying everything, one-by-one...

At any rate, as far as packages go, Minion Pro is fairly short: around 600 lines of code or so. The bulk of the work has already been done by the original authors of MinionPro.sty.